# Value of msg.sender in call to inherited external function

Tags: solidity, inheritance

I found this in the official [solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties).

> The values of all members of msg, including msg.sender and msg.value can change for every external function call. This includes calls to library functions.

The "can change for every external function call" is too vague for me.

Does anyone know when it **does** change for an external function call?

My concrete example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract A {
    function foo() external view returns(address payable) {return msg.sender;}
}

contract B is A {
    address payable public msgSender;

    function bar() external {
        // 3 ways of doing the same thing
        msgSender = A.foo();  // does this work and who will be msgSender?
        msgSender = this.foo();  // does this work and who will be msgSender? 
        msgSender = super.foo();  // does this work and who will be msgSender? 
    }
}
```

Please take all the code as is => in the 3 notations `A.foo()` `this.foo()` `super.foo()` I am NOT talking to another deployed contract instance. With all 3 ways I want to showcase 3 (different but same) ways of calling `external functions` (`inherited` ones in this case) on a `contract` from `inside` (`internally`) that same `contract`. The 3 ways basically just vary in their `scope` or explicitness I believe.

Back to my main question: 
**Who is the `msg.sender` emitted in the `EmitMsgSender` `event` emitted by the `call` to `A/this/super.foo()` in my example?**
Is it `contract B`'s `address payable` or is it the `address` that sent the `tx` to `B.bar()`?

By the way, it would make my life easier, if it were the original caller of the `B.bar()` function, and not `B`'s address.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: All of your 3 questions in the code - you can simply try and find out. I don't think that either one of them is even going to compile since function `foo` is external, and you cannot call external functions from the same contract (and since `B is A`, we're talking about the same contract here). So you probably wanna change it to `public` or `internal` and then simply give it a try and see what you get in the emitted event. BTW, you might find it easier to test the whole thing it you declare the function as `view returns (address)` and simply return `msg.sender`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your right, I'll just test it. But gonna leave the question here and supply my test results as an aswer. btw you **can** call `external` functions inside the same `contract` : " An external function f cannot be called internally (i.e. f() does not work, but this.f() works)." (see the docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters)

Comment: OK, well done for testing it and providing your own observation / analysis. Voted it upwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer, to my own questions after testing in `Remix`:

1. `A.foo()` does not work: `TypeError Member "foo" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract A)`
2. same for `super.foo()` except it says `... lookup in contract super B`
   Both 1) and 2) could be expected from the `docs` that only list `this.f()` as a way to call `external` functions from inside a contract.

And now to the interesting part: **Edits thanks to @smarx**
`this.foo()`works and it returns the `address` of `contract B` as `msg.sender`.

=> When I call an `inherited` `external` `function` `internally` (from inside the same contract), the context DID change the `msg.sender` to the `derived contract`'s `address`, who forwarded the `message` to its `base` `contract`'s `external` `function` via the special `this.function()` syntax.

The `msg.sender` is NOT preserved (as could be expected from the `solidity docs`).

However, the docs are still ambiguous:

> msg.value **can** change for every external function call.

This seems to imply that sometimes it does not change. So:
 **When does it change (in my example it did) and most of all when DOES IT NOT?**

EDIT: Answer from @smarx (paraphrased)

> the context of `msg.sender` DOES NOT change in calls to an `external` `contract` `function` when you use `delegatecall`

Comment: This doesn't match my testing. When I call `this.foo()`, `foo()` sees the contract's address as `msg.sender`.

Comment: (BTW, this has nothing to do with inheritance. If you just declare `foo()` in the same contract and use `this.foo()` to invoke it, `msg.sender` will still be the contract's address.)

Comment: Hi @smarx - I edited the code in my initial question slightly, to match exactly what I tested it in `Remix IDE` using the `JavaScript VM`. I realized I made a mistake in the `Remix IDE` initially. I accidentally only compiled and deployed `ContractA` which obviously returned my account from `foo()` . thanks for pointing this out, I will edit my answer. One question remains: the `solidity docs` are quite ambiguous ("can change for every external function call") - do you know the examples where it does NOT change? thanks!

Comment: It doesn't change when you use a `delegatecall`.