# Silence visibility warning, state mutability can be restricted to pure

Tags: solidity, compiler, solidity-coverage

Suppose I have an interface:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;

interface Foo {
  function foo() public view returns(bool);
}
```

And a simplistic implementation like a mock:

```
contract Bar is Foo {

  function foo() public view returns(bool} {
    this; // silence state mutability warning
    return true;
  }
}
```

This part:

```
this;
```

... sort of works. See here: [Function overriding versus Solidity Compiler Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76502/function-overriding-versus-solidity-compiler-warning-function-state-mutability)

It seems clean enough with `truffle compile` and `hardhat compile` but solidity-coverage still complains about it:

```
state mutability can be restricted to pure
```

Sure, but this is a false positive. We don't want to change any code. The perfectionist in me doesn't want to see alarming warnings where no issue exists.

**Is there a better way to silence the warning?**

Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The warning is a valid warning - why not use `pure`.

Comment: I guess you cannot change the interface, right?

Comment: The interface has to be `view` ... this implementation has no need to read the state, but other implementations do.

Comment: hi, have You found a better way to do it :) ?

Comment: Not yet, and I've moved on. Would be interested in a way to silence it.